# c# ews api default font style

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

i would like to send an email with the ews api.

The code-example from [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-send-email-messages-by-using-ews-in-exchange) works fine.

But it doesn't use the default font stlye.

If i send an email with outlook it use the configuration from outlook.

How could i change or set the default font style at ews with c# code in my application?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify any font in the HTML body of the message you send.

Comment: i know. But how could i get the default font or default html from an ews or outlook mail?

Comment: I am not sure where EWS stores the font settings (probably a hidden item in the Inbox folder), the Windows version of Outlook stores the default font in ReplyFontSimple in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\<OutlookVersion>\Common\MailSettings